# Track file request referrer

Tags: php

I've got a file on server, for example "file.txt". It may be requested from different domains.

Is there any way to track from which domain this file was requested and save this data somewhere?

Comment: what do you mean by "requested from different domains"?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think domain name would be your best option .. i would advice you stick to `IP address for` restrictions

You can also use `$_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']` to verify the exact script calling your file or about to load your file

Try

```
$allowedReferer = array (
        "http://me.test.com/xxx/bbb/zmy.php?",
        "https://me.why.com/xxx/bbb/zmy.axpx" ,
        "http://localhost/lab/stockoverflow/"
);

$allowedIP = array (
        "192.168.0.1",
        "192.168.0.1" ,
        "::1"
);

$file = "file.pdf"; // its can also be a value form $_GET

if (! in_array ( quickIP (), $allowedIP )) {
    die ( "IP LockDown : " . quickIP () );
}

if (! isset ( $_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'] )) {
    die ( "Missing Referer" );
}

if (! in_array ($_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'] , $allowedReferer)) {
    die ( "Referer Lockdown "  . $_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']);
}

$array = parse_url ( $_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'] );

header ( 'Content-type: application/pdf' );
header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"' );
readfile ( $file );

function quickIP() {
    return (empty ( $_SERVER ['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ? (empty ( $_SERVER ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ? $_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'] : $_SERVER ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) : $_SERVER ['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, just get the referer and store it. The variable is $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

You have two choices. Either you write a PHP script that serves the file ( http://teddy.fr/blog/how-serve-big-files-through-php ) and store the referer for that using PHP.

Alternatively, the web server keeps a log of all accessed files. You can scan this (structured) log for accesses to your file and get the referers out. There are several log analysis projects, like AWStats.